# Building Erlang projects on Windows

Tags: windows, makefile, erlang

I'm looking for a way to build an Erlang project on Windows. I have Erlang installed and all project files, including makefile, cloned from GitHub. I would like to build the project as if I was using make command on Linux and run it. What tools can I use to do that?

Comment: Depending on the version of erlang you have installed, you can use [rebar](https://github.com/basho/rebar) or [rebar3](https://www.rebar3.org/)

Comment: Just an update: I ended up installing Oracle Virtual Box on my machine and I'm now running Ubuntu on it and use it for my Erlang development needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try cygwin. https://www.cygwin.com

http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL-WIN32.html

You can either build erlang with cygwin or use gnu-make in combination with a native windows build of erlang

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking "how do I run `make` in Windows?" then you can use Cygwin, the newly-available Bash shell, or the MinGW tools. These will all give you some level of ability to run `make`, though not every makefile will work.

If you're asking "how can I build an Erlang project using a makefile?" then you are looking for [erlang.mk](https://erlang.mk). Note that [Rebar3](https://www.rebar3.org) (which is configured with Erlang terms and looks nothing like a make system) was recently selected as the "official" build tool, but erlang.mk is quite popular and is well-maintained.